# Cannot select options with Python Selenium (javascript?)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate the download process on this page: https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx

In particular, I want to be able to select any option in the "Reporting Period End Date" dropdown.

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContentHolder$DatesDropDownList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContentHolder$DatesDropDownList\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="DatesDropDownList" class="valuelabel">
        <option selected="selected" value="81">12/31/2014</option>
        <option value="80">09/30/2014</option>
        <option value="79">06/30/2014</option>
        <option value="78">03/31/2014</option>
        <option value="76">12/31/2013</option>
                ...
</select>
```

I tried the following in Selenium, but it returns an empty list:

```
url = 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
date_field = driver.find_element_by_id("DatesDropDownList")
Select(date_field).options
```

I think the issue is the javascript in the select. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Did the given solution work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page functionality expects you to select a value from the first listbox :)

So select a value from "Available Products", then the date dropdown gets populated.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx')

list1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ListBox1"))
list1.select_by_visible_text("Call Reports -- Single Period")

date_field = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("DatesDropDownList"))
date_field.select_by_visible_text("03/31/2014")
```

Comment: That gives a NoSuchElementException.